# Templated linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, template

I have created a templated linked list to take different objects. I was told to put this up for code review as it could use some improvements. To be honest, I am not completely sure when to use the 'new' keyword for all instances. Also, I am not completely confident on my use of the template syntax. I did get it to work though.

```
#ifndef TEMPLATEDLINKEDLIST_LINKEDLISTOBJS_H
#define TEMPLATEDLINKEDLIST_LINKEDLISTOBJS_H
using namespace std;
template <typename T> class Node {
public:
    T dataStored;
    Node* next = NULL;
};
int counter = 0;
template <typename T>
class LinkedList {
public:
    Node<T> *head;
    Node<T> *tail;

    LinkedList() {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }

    void AddToFront(T data);
    void display();
    void AddToEnd(T data);
    void AddAtIndex(T data, int index);
    void RemoveFromFront();
    void RemoveFromEnd();
    void RemoveTheFirst(T data);
    void RemoveAllOf(T data);
    bool ElementExists(T data);
    T Find(T data);
    int IndexOf(T data);
    string RetrieveFront();
    string RetrieveEnd();
    string Retrieve(int index);
    int Length();
    ~LinkedList();
};
     template <typename T>
 void LinkedList<T>:: AddToFront(T data) {
         Node<T>* node = new Node<T>;
         node->dataStored = data;
         if(head == NULL) {
             head = tail = node;
         }
         else{
                node->next = head;
                head = node;
         }
         counter++;
     }
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::display() {
         Node<T>* iter;
         iter = head;
         while(iter != NULL) {
             cout<<iter->dataStored<<" ";
             iter = iter->next;
         }
     }
     template <typename T> void LinkedList<T>::AddToEnd(T data) {
         Node<T>* node = new Node<T>;
         node->dataStored = data;
         if(head==nullptr) {
             head = tail = node;
         }
         else {
             tail->next = node;
             tail = node;
         }
         counter++;
     }
    template<typename T> int LinkedList<T>::Length()
     {
         return counter;
     }
template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList() {
        Node<T>* current = head;
        while (current != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
            delete current;
            head = current;
        }

    }
    template<typename T>
    void LinkedList<T>::AddAtIndex(T data, int index) {
        if(index>counter){
            cout<<"Out of bounds";
        }
        else if(index == 0) {
//            node = head->next;
//            head = node;
            AddToFront(data);
        }
        else if(index == counter) {
//            tail->next = node;
//            tail = node;
              AddToEnd(data);
        }
        else{
            int x = 0;
            Node<T>* node = new Node<T>;
            node->dataStored = data;
            Node<T>* temp = head;
            Node<T>* prev;
            while(x!=index){
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp->next;
                x++;
            }
            prev->next = node;
            node->next = temp;
        }
        counter++;
    }
template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::RemoveFromFront() {
    if(head==nullptr){
        cout<<"Empty";
    }
    else {
        Node<T> *node;
        node = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete node;
        counter--;
    }
}
template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::RemoveFromEnd() {
    if(head==tail) {
        cout<<"Empty";
    }
    else {
        Node<T> *node;
        node = head;
        Node<T> *temp;
        temp = tail;
        while (node->next != tail) {
            node = node->next;
        }
        tail = node;
        delete temp;
        counter--;
    }
}
//template<typename T>
//void LinkedList<T>::RemoveTheFirst(T data) {
//    Node<T>* node;
//    node = head;
//    if(head->dataStored==data) {
//        RemoveFromFront();
//        counter--;
//    }
//    else{
//        Node<T>* temp;
//        while(node->dataStored!=data || node!=tail) {
//            node = node->next;
//            if(node->data==data) {
//                temp = node;
//                break;
//            }
//        }
//        delete
//    }
//}

#endif //TEMPLATEDLINKEDLIST_LINKEDLISTOBJS_H
```

And main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedListObjs.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
//    Node<int>* node1 = new Node<int>;
//    node1->dataStored = 3;
//    cout<<node1->dataStored;
    LinkedList<int>* link = new LinkedList<int>;
    link->AddToFront(2);

    link->AddToFront(2);

    link->AddToFront(3);

    link->AddToEnd(1);

    link->AddAtIndex(5,3);
    link->RemoveFromFront();
//    link->RemoveFromFront();
//    link->RemoveFromFront();
//    link->RemoveFromFront();
//    link->RemoveFromFront();
//    link->RemoveFromFront();
    link->display();
   // link->AddAtIndex(0,1);
    cout<<endl<<link->Length()<<endl;
    delete link;
    return 0;
}
```

The linked list is not completely finished, but it is functional enough to get a review.

Answer (score 5):

##### Code style

Put spaces in between the class declarations and between method definitions. Right now, it's difficult to determine where one code block ends and another begins. Also, fix the code indentation. The definition for `AddAtIndex()` is indented as if it's a part of the definition of `~LinkedList()`

Spacing and indentation act like paragraph breaks in writing. It helps the reader of the code to see the structure before getting into the details.

##### Undefined methods

The following methods have no definition. They aren't called, so the code still compiles, but they should be deleted.

```
void RemoveTheFirst(T data);
void RemoveAllOf(T data);
bool ElementExists(T data);
T Find(T data);
int IndexOf(T data);
string RetrieveFront();
string RetrieveEnd();
string Retrieve(int index);
```

I have some questions about these methods. What would `T Find(T data)` even do? Give the user the same data that the user searched for? Also, the last three methods should return `T` rather than `string`.

##### The size of the list should be a member of the list

Why is the `counter` variable in the global namespace? This prevents more than one linked list from being created in a program. Consider the following code:

```cpp
LinkedList<int> l1, l2;
l1.AddToFront(1);
l2.AddToFront(3);
cout << l1.Length() << " " << l2.Length() << endl;
```

What would you expect the output to be? It prints `2 2`. That's because both `LinkedList` objects modify the same `counter` variable. The counter should be a member of the `LinkedList` class so that every list keeps track of its own length.

```cpp
template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
    public:
    Node<T>* head;
    Node<T>* tail;
    int counter;

    LinkedList()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        counter = 0;
    }

    // ...
}
```

##### Use constructors

If you are using C++11 or later, then you can initialize the `Node` much more simply.

```cpp
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::AddToFront(T data)
{
    head = new Node<T>{data, head};
    if(tail == NULL) {
        tail = head
    }
    counter++;
}
```

In your current code, it takes three lines to create a new `Node`: the creation with `new`, setting the `dataStored` member, and setting the `next` member.

A similar change can simplify the `AddToEnd()` method

```cpp
template <typename T> void LinkedList<T>::AddToEnd(T data)
{
    if(head == nullptr) {
        AddToFront(data);
    }
    else {
        tail->next = new Node<T>{ data, NULL };
        tail = tail->next;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

I took the liberty of reusing `AddToFront()` for the empty list case to reduce the amount of code repetition.

##### Don't use `new` when you don't have to

In the `main()` function, you use `new` to create a `LinkedList` and then manually delete it at the end.

```cpp
LinkedList<int>* link = new LinkedList<int>;
// ...
delete link;
```

Whenever you don't need a pointer (which is almost always the case), just make a `LinkedList` as if it were any other variable.

```cpp
LinkedList<int> link;
// ...
```

When you declare objects like this, you don't need to manually delete the object. The destructor for the object will run automatically when program leaves the scope where the object was created (at the end of `main()` for this list).

##### Correcting the destructor

The logic in your destructor is clear but subtly wrong.

```cpp
template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
    Node<T>* current = head;
    while(current != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
        delete current;
        head = current;
    }
}
```

First, the first element is never deleted. The initial value of `current` is `head`, then the first time through the loop, `current` is set to `current->next` before `delete current` is called. The first element is missed. Second, the next iteration through the loop calls for `current->next` after `delete current`. This causes the program to exit with an error when a `LinkedList` is destructed.

The process for the destructor is simple: while the list is not empty, delete the first element. We have methods to do both of these things, so let's use them:

```cpp
template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
    while(Length() > 0) {
        RemoveFromFront();
    }
}
```

Now the program ends with no errors.

##### Publicity and Privacy

The purpose of a class is to present the user with a simple interface to a complex data structure, much in the same way the gas pedal, brake pedal, and steering wheel present a simple interface to a complex motor vehicle. As much as possible of the inner workings of a class should be hidden so that the user of the class is not tempted to mess with important internals.

```cpp
template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
    private:
    Node<T>* head;
    Node<T>* tail;
    int counter;

    public:
    LinkedList()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        counter = 0;
    }

    // ...
}
```

This change prevents users of `LinkedList` from modifying a list in ways that make it stop functioning. Otherwise, for example, a user could write `list.counter = 2000;` so that `Length()` returns the wrong answer.

##### Error handling

At the moment, there is no way to handle when invalid inputs are used in the `LinkedList` methods. For example,

```cpp
template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::AddAtIndex(T data, int index)
{
    if(index > counter) {
        cout << "Out of bounds";
    }
    // ...
}
```

There is no way for the program to intervene when the code tries to add an element way beyond the end of the list. Right now, the list is unchanged and there's nothing to indicate that the method call had no effect other than some text printed to the console (which the program doesn't read).

One way to indicate that the method call failed is to change the signature so that it returns `true` on success or `false` on failure:

```cpp
template<typename T>
bool LinkedList<T>::AddAtIndex(T data, int index)
{
    if(index > counter) {
        return false;
    }
    else if(index == 0) {
        AddToFront(data);
    }
    else if(index == counter) {
        AddToEnd(data);
    }
    else {
        int x = 0;
        Node<T>* node = new Node<T>;
        node->dataStored = data;
        Node<T>* temp = head;
        Node<T>* prev = NULL;
        while(x != index) {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
            x++;
        }
        prev->next = node;
        node->next = temp;
    }
    counter++;
    return true;
}
```

A better option is to throw an exception. The return value of a method can be ignored, but an exception must be handled or else the program ends.

```cpp
#include <exception>

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::AddAtIndex(T data, int index)
{
    if(index > counter) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Insertion point beyond end of list.")
    }
    // ...
}
```

This also goes for the methods that remove items from the list in the case of an empty list.

##### Use representative data types

The `counter` variable that records the length of the list should be an unsigned type since it should never be negative. So, `counter` should be `unsigned int` or, more to the standard, `std::size_t`, which requires `#include <cstddef>`.

##### Initialize variables upon creation

There are many places where a variable is declared and given a value in two separate lines.

```cpp
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::display()
{
    Node<T>* iter;
    iter = head;
    while(iter != NULL) {
        cout << iter->dataStored << " ";
        iter = iter->next;
    }
}
```

The `iter` variable can be given a value immediately.

```cpp
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::display()
{
    Node<T>* iter = head;
    while(iter != NULL) {
        cout << iter->dataStored << " ";
        iter = iter->next;
    }
}
```

##### Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`

The value `nullptr` is specifically defined to represent a null pointer and doesn't require any other files to be `#included`.

##### What is a linked list for?

Since the linked list has to be traversed to find the index location for `AddAtIndex()`, a program that uses this method a lot will be very slow. There's an argument to be made that such methods should be deleted because it shouldn't be easy to write slow code.

##### Bugs

1. In the method `RemoveFromFront()`, removing the last item from the list leaves the `tail` pointer dangling (pointing at deleted data). You need to check if the list is empty and fix the `tail` pointer.

```cpp
template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::RemoveFromFront() {
    if(head==nullptr){
        cout<<"Empty";
    }
    else {
        Node<T> *node = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete node;
        counter--;
        if(head == nullptr) {
            tail = nullptr;
        }
    }
}
```

2. In the method `RemoveFromEnd()` the condition `head == tail` is true when the list has zero **or one** items. The list is empty when `head == nullptr` or `counter == 0`. However, `head == tail` does require a special case. If `head == tail`, then `node->next == nullptr` in the first `while()` loop iteration, so the `tail` will be missed.

```cpp
template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::RemoveFromEnd() {
    if(head == nullptr) {
        cout<<"Empty";
    }
    else if(head == tail) {
        RemoveFromFront();
    }
    else {
        Node<T> *node = head;
        Node<T> *temp = tail;
        while (node->next != tail) {
            node = node->next;
        }
        tail = node;
        delete temp;
        counter--;
    }
}
```

3. In the same method, the new `tail` still links to the deleted `Node`. It's `next` pointer should be set to `nullptr`.

```cpp
template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::RemoveFromEnd() {
    if(head == nullptr) {
        cout<<"Empty";
    }
    else if(head == tail) {
        RemoveFromFront();
    }
    else {
        Node<T> *node = head;
        Node<T> *temp = tail;
        while (node->next != tail) {
            node = node->next;
        }
        tail = node;
        tail->next = nullptr;
        delete temp;
        counter--;
    }
}
```

We can also rewrite this without the `temp` variable to reduce its complexity.

```cpp
template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::RemoveFromEnd() {
    if(head == nullptr) {
        cout<<"Empty";
    }
    else if(head == tail) {
        RemoveFromFront();
    }
    else {
        Node<T> *node = head;
        while (node->next != tail) {
            node = node->next;
        }
        delete tail;
        tail = node;
        tail->next = nullptr;
        counter--;
    }
}
```

Comment: A short question: Is there a reason why you didn't recommend using `std::unique_ptr` to store head and tail nodes?

Comment: @Green绿色 I thought it was a little too complicated to mention those. There's the issue of deep call stacks in the destructor (especially if the Node class uses unique_ptr). Also why the head should be a unique_ptr and not the tail to avoid double deletion. I thought my review was long enough without those subtleties.

Comment: The callstack issue can be avoided by `std::move()`ing the `next` node in a `while`-loop. In fact it's similar to how OP wrote the destructor.

Comment: I was reading through this post, wondering about smart pointers as @Green绿色
suggests. @G.Sliepen could you elaborate on how you'd use `std::move()` etc so that a smart_pointer could be used for `Node`, or perhaps suggest a link pls ?

Comment: ... (ST::CR has a 5min comment limit, thus this further comment) You've given us a clue, with [std::forward_list](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/forward_list) which contains a huge amount of macros and headers such as `xmemory`, is there a simpler way ? The code quoted (I'm surmising) is for a large number of architectures & OSs

Comment: `std::forward_list` does not require any macros or non-standard headers. You are looking at a particular *implementation* of `std::forward_list`… which is not a good idea (standard library implementations are notoriously complex, ugly, and not good examples of general C++ code). You should be looking at the *interface* of `std::forward_list`… as described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list), for example.

Comment: @Lozminda I just tried replacing all the pointers with `std::unique_ptr`s, and it was more involved than I though. A lot of non-obvious changes were needed: making a constructor for `Node` with an rvalue-reference parameter for the `next` member, keeping `tail` as a raw pointer, needing `std::move` in several places, needing `get()` when iterating through the list. There's a lot to explain that would make this review much longer than it already is.

Comment: @indi I did indeed look there first, but it gives no idea of the implementation of the interface, (**unless I've missed something important which is always possible**) . I *believe*  the OP and subsequent comments are about how to write an implementation, and specifically how one might use a smart pointer and std::move to implement `Node`. I guess sometimes raw pointers are the right tool ?

Comment: Nope, you’ve missed nothing; that page does indeed only tell you the interface. When I’m coding, for copyright reasons I usually avoid looking at implementations and just try to figure out an implementation based on the interface. If you are looking for an implementation… I don’t know where to look either, but I can say that looking at actual standard library implementations is unwise. For a lot of reasons, std implementations are usually very, very bad examples to learn from. (Also, I agree that this isn’t really a good use case for `unique_ptr`; raw pointers are actually a better idea here.)

Answer (score 5):

Please don't do this:

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

It's especially harmful in a header file, where it will pollute the global namespace of every translation unit that includes the header.

---

> ```
> string RetrieveFront();
> string RetrieveEnd();
> string Retrieve(int index);
> ```

There's no definition for `string` in scope.  If `std::string` is intended, then we need to include `<string>`.  It's not clear why the return type is `string` rather than `T` or `T const&`, though.

We also need to include `<cstdlib>` to define `NULL` - though I recommend changing to use `nullptr` instead.  And `<iostream>` to define `std::cout` - though most uses seem more appropriate for `std::clog` or `std::cerr`.

---

> ```
> template <typename T> class Node {
> ```

This type should probably be internal to the `LinkedList`, as it's not intended to be user-visible.

---

> ```
> {
> public:
>     T dataStored;
>     Node* next = NULL;
> };
> ```

I recommend using `struct` rather than `class` when all values are public.  And this public data adds to the recommendation to make this a private inner class of `LinkedList` so that users can't corrupt the list structure.

---

> ```
> int counter = 0;
> ```

Avoid global variables.  In this case, the usage suggests that this shouldn't be global at all; it should be a member of `LinkedList`, as it represents the length of the list.  At present, it represents the total length of *all* lists, which isn't so useful.  Also, I recommend changing its type to `std::size_t` so that it can represent any size of list.

---

> ```
> public:
>     Node<T> *head;
>     Node<T> *tail;
> ```

If a caller were to access these members directly, they could break the list invariants.   That's bad, so they should be `private` and modified only by the member functions.

Also, these pointers *own* the `Node` contents, so we need to provide copy constructor and assignment operator to prevent two lists owning the same content (which could lead to double-free):

```
    LinkedList(LinkedList const&) = delete;
    void operator=(LinkedList const&) = delete;
```

---

> ```
> LinkedList() {
>     head = NULL;
>     tail = NULL;
> }
> ```

Instead of letting the members default-initialize, then assigning new values, we should use the constructor's *initializer list* to set these:

```
    LinkedList()
        : head{nullptr},
          tail{nullptr}
    {
    }
```

Or, more simply, use in-class initialisers:

```
    Node<T> *head = nullptr;
    Node<T> *tail = nullptr;

public:
    LinkedList() = default;
```

---

> ```
>     if(index>counter){
>         std::cout<<"Out of bounds";
>     }
> ```

What about `index < 0`?  That case is easily avoided if we switch to using an unsigned type for the list length and indexes.

---

We have a memory **bug** in the destructor; it's revealed when we run under Valgrind:

```
==3999466== Invalid read of size 8
==3999466==    at 0x1095D1: LinkedList<int>::~LinkedList() (288764.cpp:86)
==3999466==    by 0x109272: main (288764.cpp:204)
==3999466==  Address 0x4dc90e8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==3999466==    at 0x4843ADF: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3999466==    by 0x1095EE: LinkedList<int>::~LinkedList() (288764.cpp:87)
==3999466==    by 0x109272: main (288764.cpp:204)
==3999466==  Block was alloc'd at
==3999466==    at 0x4840F83: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3999466==    by 0x1092D2: LinkedList<int>::AddToFront(int) (288764.cpp:48)
==3999466==    by 0x1091BB: main (288764.cpp:186)
```

Let's have a look at the cause:

> ```
> Node<T>* current = head;
> while (current != NULL) {
>     current = current->next;
>     delete current;
>     head = current;
> }
> ```

We delete `current`, then assign it to `head` (which is a *dead write* as we never read `head` again).  Then in the next iteration of the loop we access `current->next`, which is no longer accessible.

We need two pointers - one to the element we're deleting, and one to its successor:

```
    auto *current = head;
    while (current) {
        auto *next = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }
```

---

The `main()` function exercises some of the code, but doesn't *test* it.  It would be more useful if it returned `EXIT_FAILURE` if expectations are not met.

---

This isn't a full review, but should be enough to improve your program for a second round of review.

Answer (score 5):

You already got two very detailed answers from Toby Speight and Mark H, I just want to add a few things:

## Make it look more like `std::forward_list`

The standard library also comes with a singly-linked list, called [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list). You'll notice it has a somewhat similar set of member functions, but they are named differently. For example, your `AddToFront()` is called `push_front()` in `std::forward_list`. If you would rename your member functions so they match those of the standard library list, then suddenly you get several advantages:

- Programmers familiar with the standard library will find it easier to work with your class, since they don't need to learn a new set of names.
- You can more easily exchange a `std::forward_list` for a `LinkedList` and vice versa if they have the same interface.
- Standard library algorithms will be able to work with your class if it follows the same conventions as other standard containers. For example, if you have a `push_front()`, then [`std::front_inserter()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/front_inserter) can work directly on `LinkedList`s.

This can be taken even further, with even bigger rewards, if you:

## Add iterators

A lot of algorithms, and even language features such as [range-based `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), will be able to work with your class if you add standard iterator support. Basically, add a `begin()` and `end()` function that return iterators to the start and end of the list. An iterator is just another `class` with a few member functions, like `operator++()` to advance the iterator, `operator==()` to check if two iterators point to the same element, and `operator*()` to dereference the iterator and get access to the value it is pointing to.

While this might seem like a bit of work, which it is, it actually allows you to simplify your code in other areas. Consider that the only member function that currently can iterate over all the elements of a `LinkedList` is `display()`. However, that function can only print its elements to `std::cout`. That's not very flexible. Maybe you want to print them to a file? Sum all the elements? Do something else? You could add more and more member functions, but it will never be enough and it will hopelessly complicate your class. If you add support for iterators, then you don't need a `display()` member function; the caller can just do:

```
LinkedList<int> list;
…
for (auto value: list) {
    std::cout << value << " ";
}
```

Or with C++23's ability to format ranges, you will be able to just write:

```
LinkedList<int> list;
…
std::print("{}\n", list);
```

But you can also use other [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), like:

```
LinkedList<int> list;
…
auto sum = std::accumulate(list.begin(), list.end());
```

There are [tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=custom%20iterators%20c%2B%2B%20tutorial) that can help you write your own iterators.

## Going further

A very good excercise would be to implement *all* of [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list), paying attention to all the details, like for example why there are multiple overloads for some functions, when parameters are passed by value, (`const`) reference or r-value reference, why some functions are `noexcept` and others are not, and so on. This will be quite a bit of work though, but might give you a very good understanding of C++.